# Integrating R307 fingerprint scanner with Android

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api, android-hardware

In my application I need to capture and store fingerprint data and use it for authentication. As Android fingerprint API does not provide functionality to store fingerprints per user, I have decided to use external scanner. I am willing to use R307 scanner module. Is there any sdk available to integrate it with Android.

Comment: you will need to contact your supplier or manufacturing company only they can tell that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Arduino Uno as a middleware to connect R307 to Android application. Adafruite library to integrate sensor with the Arduino. Used https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial library for Android USB communication.

The communication between Arduino and Android is a bit tricky as Arduino Uno has only 64 bytes of serial buffer size. You will need to establish some kind of protocol-based communication (I used "/End" as my String End command).